# What does Husserl mean by 'purity'?

Tags: consciousness, phenomenology, husserl

I'm reading "Ideas" by Husserl, and there are several notions I'd like to crystallise or 'locate' within my own experience.

Kant also spoke of purity, and with him it was in terms of intuition, being 'a concept of the pure understanding'.

Alongside 'understanding', I'd like to enquire of those familiar with Husserl (in particular, Ideas), what would be a good interpretation of 'pure consciousness', or 'pure ego'?

Also, what would a consciousness or ego look like were it 'muddied', 'unclear' or 'impure'?

Comment: Husserl inherited the term from Kant and used it similarly. In Kant it meant something (e.g. intuition) independent of any empirical input. Pure consciousness in Husserl is the side of consciousness completely independent of the external world. In *Ideas* It is detected as the residual left after bracketing all assumptions about the external world in the 'universal' *epoché*. There is some discussion of it in [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/husserl/#PheEpo).

Comment: @Conifold I thought Kant applied the term *purity* to both sensibility and understanding so that phenomena are given in pure sensibility and noumena are given in pure understanding (intellect).  Is this not correct?

Comment: @nwr He did, and also to reason. In all three cases "pure", as attached to intuitions, judgments, concepts, propositions, meant independent of empirical experience in most of CPR. I discussed his initial meandering on its meaning in [Did Kant classify the same proposition as both pure and impure a priori?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/64372/9148) But empirical phenomena are "given in pure sensibility" only in the sense that pure forms of sensibility, space and time, frame them. The only thing pure sensibility produces on its own is mathematics.

Comment: @Conifold Thanks for clarifying that point for me.  I've only recently begun to familiarize myself with K's system and that was a point of confusion for me but it makes perfect sense that the term is applied to the pure intuitions of sensibility.